# Kubernetes - AWS cloud provider with custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

We have a requirement to have all our EC2 instances connected to our Active Directory that has a domain name companyname.internal.

When we try to spin up the Kubernetes cluster with the kubeadm, it picks up the AWS internal hostname for some reason and fails to register. I have ensured that the EC2 instance local host name and the metadata from the EC2 metadata points to the correct hostname.

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname
```

> ip-10-202-1-205.company.internal

However, in the kubelet logs, I can see the AWS standard hostname. Is there a way to override this?

```
2443 status_manager.go:485] Failed to get status for pod "kube-controller-manager-ip-10-202-1-205.us-gov-west-1.compute.internal_kube-system(xxxx)": Get https://api.xxx:443/let[2443]: E0917 02:50:07.887059    
2443 kubelet_node_status.go:94] Unable to register node "ip-10-202-1-205.us-gov-west-1.compute.internal" with API server: Post https://api.xxx:443/api/v1/nodes: EOF
```

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11543) is referenced specifically from [the code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/v1.15.3/staging/src/k8s.io/legacy-cloud-providers/aws/aws.go#L2151-L2158) and the issue actually has some fresh comments saying it is still a problem; [one comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/11543#issuecomment-334536308) suggested trying to have kubelet advertise itself using its `InternalIP` instead

Answer (score 0):

You can add the --node-name option on the kubeadm init command.

e.g.

```
kubeadm init --node-name ec2-18-189-6-14.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com --pod-address-cidr=****
```

Then you will see this output.

```
root@ip-172-31-27-139:/home/ubuntu# kubectl get nodes
 NAME                                STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
 ec2-18-189-6-14.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com   Ready   master   10m   v1.15.3
```